# Pushing/popping in a loop without dynamic typing

Tags: java, python, types, stack, static-typing

*---Third and hopefully final EDIT---*
Firstly let me say that this is a question regarding code condensing and has almost nothing to do with stacks. In the following code you will notice every block is separated by openGl pushmarix() and popmatrix()

THIS is the problem! In this method there are simply too many push/pop calls and I want to condense this so that push and pop are called only once each.

```
    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    Vec2 torPos = ...;
    glTranslatef(...);
    glRotated(...);
    glRectf(...);
    glPopMatrix();      //<---------  pop matrix

    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    Vec2 armPos = i.arm.getPosition().mul(30);
    glTranslatef(...);
    glRotated(...);
    glRectf(...);
    glPopMatrix()       //<---------  pop matrix

    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    GL11.glColor3f(...);
    Vec2 anchor = new Vec2(0,0);
    i.torsoArmJoint.getAnchorA(anchor);
    glTranslatef(....);
    glRectf(...);
    glPopMatrix();      //<---------- pop matrix
```

The most sensible way (it seems) to do this is by implementing a for loop. This is where the question comes in... because frankly it doesn't matter if there is some other way to solve the problem in the preceding code.

What I want to know is... how, in java, can you have a loop such as a push/pop context where you MUST have line1, followed by -whatever- then followed by line2 where the order MUST be line1, code, line2.

It seems sensible to transform the previous code into this:

```
    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    method1();
    glPopMatrix();      //<---------  pop matrix

    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    method2();
    glPopMatrix()       //<---------  pop matrix

    glPushMatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
    method3();
    glPopMatrix();      //<---------- pop matrix
```

or even  this:

```
object1.pushmatrix();    //<---------  push matrix
object1.method();
object1.popmatrix();     //<---------  push matrix

object2.pushmatrix();    //<---------  push matrix
object2.method();
object2.popmatrix();     //<---------  push matrix

object3.pushmatrix();    //<---------  push matrix
object3.method();
object3.popmatrix();     //<---------  push matrix
```

But as you can see, there is a pattern here (hence the comments) which is that I have to continually call these push/pop methods for each procedure. In python, I could simply append all of the method calls into a list and then iterate through the list with a for loop like this:

```
methodList = [method1, method2, method3]
for method in methodList:
    glPushMatrix()     //<---------  push matrix
    method()
    glPopMatrix()      //<---------- pop matrix
```

Now if you don't know python just understand that there is a list of calls, then you invoke the calls iin the for loop as 'method'. As you can see, this would solve the problem because now there is only one push and one pop. However I have no idea how to do this in java.

Comment: Could you explain this for people who do not know python

Comment: This is hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish without context.

Comment: Oh, and as for your name, coding hard I guess would be better than hard coding.

Comment: yeah that is the idea sterling... hahaha

Comment: Nobody knows how to do this?

Comment: if your language does not support dynamic typing, you can always overcome it with virtual functions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach will be to group all of the method inside a dummy class and use reflection to access it. Below is the example of the implementation:

```
public class StackExample {

  // Other declaration here ----------

  public static void main(String[] args){

    MethodCollection collection = new MethodCollection();

    String[] methods = {"method1", "method2", "method3"};

    // requires to catch exception just in case the method does not exist
    try {
        for (String a : methods) {
            glPushMatrix(); // <----- Push matrix
            MethodCollection.class.getMethod(a, null).invoke(collection,null);
            glPopMatrix();  // <----- Pop matrix
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

 static class MethodCollection {

    /**
     * Empty constructor
     */
    public MethodCollection(){}

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("Method 1");
    }

    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("Method 2");
    }

    public void method3(){
        System.out.println("Method 3");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: updated solution without switch statement. Should be closer to python style except you need to perform try-catch exception.

Comment: Is it possible to search for the method in the collection object instead of the class?

Comment: And also, is it possible to access the methods directly rather than using the String[] 'methods' as a pointer list?

Comment: By the way I do think this is awesome. When I first read about java reflection I felt like there was a lot of potential but never really tried it out.

Comment: Yup, you can access the method directly, just simply replace the methods with string. If you like using interpreter language, you can try groovy or jython.